# How do I run adb on a mac terminal?

Tags: android-studio, adb

```
adb shell run-as /data/data/com.mypackagename
```

returns

> adb command not found

though I see adb in the directory (`/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`)

Answer (score 79):

You just need to add this path to your bash profile and source it:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

adb devices
```

Comment: bash profile is the configure file for bash under your user home folder `~` which is invisible by default.

Comment: if you don't have `~/.bash_profile`, just create it: `touch ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I configured all environment variables, but the strangest thing is that even inside the platform-tools folder adb does not run on the mac terminal, it appears as a command not found.

Comment: @JustCase could you print the info: `ls -al  ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/ | grep adb` and if you go into the folder you need use `./adb` to run the command: for example `./adb --version`

Answer (score 15):

If you are in that directory, you can run it with a leading dot-slash, i.e. `./adb shell run-as /data/data/com.mypackagename`.

In general, you might want to add that directory to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Which directory do you mean by `that directory`?

Comment: The directory `adb` is located in. In OP's case: `/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`. Nowadays I would recommend installing `adb` through Homebrew: `brew cask install android-platform-tools`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

If you are using **Catalina**:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
adb devices
```

Answer (score 11):

The first step, you should get android sdk directory path by open:

**Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK**

The path will be show here. example: /Users/*thisismyaccount*/Library/Android/sdk

Next, you open Terminal and type command as below:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/*thisismyaccount*/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

adb devices
```

Answer (score 2):

For Xamarin Studio users, this is a copy/paste from the [Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/63426/#Comment_63426)

> From Xamarin Studio, go to Tools, then select "Open Android SDK Command Prompt". This will open a terminal window and automatically navigate you to the Android SDK location. From there you can use the ADB command.

Answer (score 1):

As HuyTTQ said, first check your android SDK path.

Then export it:

```
export ADB="/Users/your_username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"

$ADB devices
```

this will only work temporarily for this opened terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my workflow:

- Navigate to the platform-tools folder on your computer where you
  placed your Android SDK/platform-tools.
- If the folder in this path is named "Android SDK" then rename that folder to "AndroidSDK" i.e. remove the space from the folder name.
- open the platform-tools folder and right click on the "adb" file and choose "get info"
  [image: Get info of adb file to get path]
- Copy the path from the "get info" pop up window:

[image: copy path to adb file]

- place copied path into your .bash_profile file via the Text Edit:

[image: line in bash]

- Save your .bash_profile file.
- Launch new window in the terminal
  The terminal window should now be in your platform-tools folder:

[image: terminal prompt]

Now, as @Xin Meng mentions above, your adb commands now use the following syntax: "./adb + command" i.e. "./adb --version"

p.s. You can use this method for placing other paths into your .bash_profile file. Just uncomment all other paths with the # symbol, save file, launch a new terminal window and voila!