# Unable to locate adb on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, react-native, android-studio, adb, platform-tools

I am starting to learn how to do mobile programming with ReactNative on an android environment. I’m using MacOS Catalina and I’ve installed android studio and react-native-cli. I ran `react-native init ShoppingList` which passed

```
Downloading template, 
Copying template, 
Processing template
```

but failed at `Installing CocoaPods dependencies` because I wasn't at the latest OS yet(I hope this is not part of the problem because I don’t have enough memory to upgrade OS)

I’ve referred to a suggestion inside [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27443), which asks me to run

```
npm uninstall -g react-native react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native react-native-cli
react-native start --reset-cache
```

I’ve also deleted the node_modules and `npm install` at the root of the project. Then at the root of the project I ran `react-native run-android`.

Which gave me the following error

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/prashin/Test/ShoppingList/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Inside Android Studio, the following are installed

```
Android 11.0(R),
Android SDK Build-Tools, 
Android Emulator 30.2.6, 
Android SDK-Platform-Tools 30.0.5, 
Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) 7.5.1
```

I created a `Pixel 2 Device` with `Release name R(API Level 30`), and pressed the Play button countless times, it gives me the error of `AVD Manager: Unable to locate ADB`.

This is my `.bash_profile` file.

```
source ~/.profile

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

##
# Your previous /Users/prashin/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/prashin/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2019-10-23_at_18:32:04
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2019-10-23_at_18:32:04: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/prashin/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
# export PATH="$PATH:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
# export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.31-macos10.14-x86_64/bin
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

And I do see an adb executable inside platform-tools according to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1419201/unable-to-locate-adb-when-using-android-studio).

What could I be missing here which is preventing me from running my basic application on the simulator? Do inform me if more information is needed.

**Edit**

A suggested solution of switching to `.zprofile` changed the error message instead. It got stuck at `info launching emulator` for 30s before producing the error below.

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
Skipping device 'emulator-5554' (emulator-5554): Device is OFFLINE.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No online devices found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Answer (score 0):

With Catalina, Apple has changed the default shell to zsh. Therefore you have to rename your configuration files. `.bashrc` is now `.zshrc` and `.bash_profile` is now `.zprofile`. Move the contents of your `.bash_profile` to a new `.zprofile` file and restart your terminal. Run the app again with new environment variables in place.

Comment: While the emulator does appear now for both the `play` button as well as `react-native run-android`, I'm still getting the error on the `play` button of "unable to locate adb". For the command, the error has changed to "Could not start emulator within 30 seconds". I have pasted the full error message in my original post.

Comment: Can you try running adb devices and see if your device is being listed in the devices list?

Comment: I tried setting up for Catalina according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970352/how-do-i-run-adb-on-a-mac-terminal/27970907 and I only see `emulator-5544 unauthorized`, what is the expected output here?

Comment: can you try ```adb kill-server``` and run ```adb-devices``` again?. Android emulators have USB debugging enabled by default.

if everything was working you would've got something like this. ```emulator-5544   device```

Comment: I still get back the same output. It always says Launching emulator, and then 30s it says it is offline

Comment: were you still getting `emulator-5544   unauthorized ` with `adb devices` command even after the `adb kill-server`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225522/discussion-between-prashin-jeevaganth-and-nithinpp).

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting the terminal made the trick for me...